# Website screen resolution not showing full width

Tags: html, css, web, styles, screen-resolution

[image: website screen resolution less 15px in console]

[image: website screen style]

The website screen resolution for a 1366 x 768 shows 1351px width in Chrome. The same for 1920 x 1080 shows 1905px width. I have checked padding, margin and border and everything are 0. Anyone knows where this 15px goes?

I am not just talking about my website. It is there in every website we take. Just try Inspect here itself in StackOverflow and click on body tag to know its size.

Comment: Possibly the actual width of the browser.

Comment: Its the width of the right scrollbar that takes up 15px.

Comment: Yes, it is the scrollbar. I tried `overflow-y: hidden;` Thank you for replying @DanyalImran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That might be **width** of the scroll bar.

Comment: Yes, it is the scrollbar. I tried `overflow-y: hidden;` Thank you for replying @Sa Si Kumar

Answer (score -1):

Add position into your style sheet, something like this:

`position:fixed`

**Makes position fixed relative to viewport**

if that doesn't work, try:

`position:absolute`

**Makes position fixed relative to document**

Comment: It is the scrollbar @Cheyyy . I tried `overflow-y: hidden;` Thank you @Cheyyy for replying